# Example for Authenticating using AWS Cognito (boto3)

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, boto3, amazon-cognito, facebook-authentication

I am trying AWS Cognito using boto3. 
I find it difficult to understand by reading the AWS documentation.
I am looking for an example or tutorial which has a step-by-step explanation.

I already have a facebook app and Cognito identity pool created.

Something like [backspace Cognito tutorial for node.js](http://backspace.technology/learn-aws-cognito-id3.html)

Answer (score 14):

I found couple of examples for integrating with Cognito using boto3.

1. [Amazon AWS Cognito and Python Boto3 to establish AWS connection and upload file to Bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28989054/amazon-aws-cognito-and-python-boto3-to-establish-aws-connection-and-upload-file)
2. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=685264

You also take a look at the boto3 API documentation for [Cognito Identity](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/cognito-identity.html) and [Cognito Sync](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/cognito-sync.html) for more details.